# While loop in Java looping back round before Threads are finished

Tags: java, while-loop

I am having trouble with regards to a while loop which will run a menu system.

This is the code i am using. Each thread, or Borrower, performs tasks simultaneously with sleep() commands in each. The issue I am now having is once each Borrower Thread is run e.g

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < borrowCount; i++) {
    model.getBorrowers().add(new Borrower(i+1,model.getLibrary(),model.runs));

model.librarian().start();

for(Borrower b : model.getBorrowers()) {
    b.start();
}
```

The Borrowers begin, however, due to sleep() commands being involved the While loop comes back around and reprints the menu within the output of the Threads.

Is there any way to ensure that the While loop only loops back around once all threads are completed?

The following is the code i am using:

**** Edited and Updated Code *****

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LibraryModel implements Runnable{
  Library library = new Library();
  Librarian librarian;
  ArrayList<Borrower> BorrowArray = new ArrayList<Borrower>();
  int runs = 0;
  Boolean isActive = true;

public LibraryModel() {
    library.AddBooks();
}

public static void main(String[]args) 
{
    int borrowCount = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Library Simulator\n");


    LibraryModel model = new LibraryModel();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = sc.next();
    char quit = 'y';

    while(quit != 'q')  {

    String a = sc.next();
    System.out.println("\n[S = start, A = About, Q = quit]");

    switch (a) {

        case "S":
           System.out.println("Please enter the number of Borrowers\n");
           borrowCount = sc.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Please enter how many runs the Program will run");
           model.runs = sc.nextInt();

           model.librarian = new Librarian(model.library,model.runs);

           for(int i = 0 ;i < borrowCount; i++) {
                model.getBorrowers().add(new Borrower(i+1,model.getLibrary(),model.runs));
                }
                model.librarian().start();

                for(Borrower b : model.getBorrowers()) {
                    b.start();
                }
        break;


        case "A":
        break;

        case "Q" :
            quit = 'q';
        break;


        default :
            System.out.println("Incorrect Entry, please enter a correct");
        break;
    }
}
```

Requested Code involving the Borrower :

```
package model;

public class Borrower extends Thread {

private int noOfBooks;
private Set<Book> BooksBorrowed;
private Set<Integer> booksRequested;
private int id;
private int runs;
private Library library;
private Random randSleep = new Random();

public Borrower(int id, Library library, int runs) {

    this.library = library;
    this.id = id;
    this.runs = runs;
    noOfBooks = 1;

    }

public Borrower(){}

public String getLoans() {
    String output = "";
    for(Book b : BooksBorrowed) {
        output +=" "+b.getBookId()+" ";
    }
    return output;
}

public void run()
{   
    try {
        Initialize();

        for(int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            RequestBooks();
            ReturnBooks();
        }

    } finally {}
}

public synchronized void Initialize() {

    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    Random r = new Random();
    noOfBooks = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Borrower "+id+" Starting");

    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void RequestBooks () {

    Random r2 = new Random();
    Book temp = null;

    ArrayList<Book>books = new ArrayList<Book>(library.getBooks());
    ArrayList<Integer>Chosen = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < noOfBooks; i++){
        int index = r2.nextInt(books.size());
        temp = books.get(index);
        int tempId = temp.getBookId();
        Chosen.add(tempId);
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("\nBorrower "+id+" requests " +noOfBooks+" Books from Library ");

    booksRequested = new HashSet<Integer>(Chosen);

    String requestedBooks = "";

    for(Integer bookid : Chosen) {
        requestedBooks = requestedBooks+bookid+" ";
        booksRequested.add(bookid);

    }
    System.out.println("Borrower "+id+" request Books: "+requestedBooks);

    BooksBorrowed = library.RQST(id,booksRequested);
    ArrayList<Book> chosenBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
    chosenBooks.addAll(BooksBorrowed);

    System.out.println("Books requested by Borrower "+id+" : "+requestedBooks+"\n");

    String receivedBooks = "";
    Book[]BookArray = BooksBorrowed.toArray(new Book[BooksBorrowed.size()]);
    for(Book b : BookArray) {
        receivedBooks = receivedBooks+b.getBookId()+" ";
    }

    System.out.println("Borrower "+id+" Books recieved :"+receivedBooks);
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    notifyAll();

}

public synchronized void ReturnBooks() {
    Set<Integer> BooksReturned;
    ArrayList<Integer> returningBooks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String returnedBooks = "";
    ArrayList<Book> borrowed = new ArrayList<Book>(BooksBorrowed);

    for (Book b : borrowed) {
        returningBooks.add(b.getBookId());
        returnedBooks = returnedBooks+b.getBookId()+" ";
    }

    BooksReturned = new HashSet<Integer>(returningBooks);

    library.RTRN(BooksReturned);
    System.out.println("\nBorrower "+id+" returned books to library: "+returnedBooks+"\n");
}
```

}

Comment: I guess you can https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html the threads, but higher abstractions (Executors) might be a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Once you started all the threads, you can add another loop that calls join on all the threads. See the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) for more info.

Rather than use Threads directly you should really use Runnable, that allows you to use some higher level abstractions. For example:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
threadPool.submit(librarian);
for (Borrower b : borrowers) {
    threadPool.submit(b);
}
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS); // do this in a loop or error if it hasnt finished?
```

Comment: Sounds like something i really should implement. However, instead of having each Thread complete itself one by one, do they all run at the same time? Im trying to implement a lock system whereby only one of the borrowers and the librarian can perform a function at one time. Is this still possible within a threadPool?

Comment: All the threads you start will run at the same time with or without a threadpool. If you only want one borrower at a time you could call start and join on the borrower in the same for loop or use locks properly. If you are running one borrower thread at a time then you dont really want to create a thread per borrower.

Comment: gave this a go and the issue is still present

Comment: Sounds like you are doing it wrong somehow. Thread.join will wait until that thread stops running. Maybe post some more of your code?

Comment: I can't see any sleeps in your code. Also you havn't posted the Librarian or Library or Book classes which doesn't help. You could really do with using the standard java naming conventions, it would make reading your code easier.

Comment: what i did was remove the sleeps because, at the current point, im also trying to implement a queue of the functions that the threads execute, which will have a sleep() between each queue entry, So i removed them. The book and the Library code i wouldnt consider are required to sort out my problem, unless you are copy pasting into say eclipse or netbeans and trying to solve it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join() to wait for the threads to finish. Start them all, then loop again calling join().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html